# Concise way of learning Bond & IR models

Tags: interest-rates, bond, reference-request

What is the most concise way to learn about bond and interest rate models from the book Mathematical Models of Financial Derivatives by Yue-Kuen Kwok? I have studied Oksendals Stochastic Differential Equations and have read Option Theory with Stochastic Analysis by Benth, so am not starting completely from scratch. I also have the book Risk Neutral Valuation by Bingham and Kiesel if this could provide a more concise way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't read Yue-Kuen Kwok's book, so it's hard for me to comment on it. Based on my personal experience, I'd recommend the following literature, depending on what you're trying to accomplish:

If you're on the quant-path, I think a lot of practitioners would recommend

- [Interest Rate Models – Theory and Prctice](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540221492) (Damiano Brigo & Fabio Mercurio): This is a very heavy book, but it covers a lot of material. Also if you only care about term structure modeling, you really just need to go over a few chapters. The book is extremely well written – easy to follow, concise, and full of examples.
- Andersen & Piterbarg's [Interest Rate Modeling](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0984422102): These three volumes are better kept as references, but they're very detailed and discuss some of the latest developments in term structure modeling (e.g., multi curve construction techniques).

If you're looking for a less rigorous treatment of the material, I'd recommend

- [Fixed Income Securities: Valuation, Risk, and Risk Management](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470109106) (Pietro Veronesi): A few of my friends who did MFE programs used this book as their FI textbook; I read through it very quickly. It has a lot of typos..., but overall, it's still an excellent book. Much much easier to follow then the two above, but full of examples and real life applications.

Finally, I'd also recommend

- [Fixed Income Securities: Tools for Today's Markets](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470891696) (Bruce Tuckman): There's a third edition now, but I much prefer the 2nd edition. The 2nd edition doesn't discuss models such as the Libor market model, but from a pedagogical perspective, it's much better written. The strength of the book is that it goes over a lot of market conventions that other books tend to ignore – and in real life trading, these details are exceptionally important. The trading examples are really well explained. If you're trying to gain perspectives on how practitioners (traders & strats) think about the market, this book is a must-read in my opinion. However, this is the least rigorous of the books I'm listing here, and doesn't go into the details of term structure modeling. It does provide lots of intuitions behind the models, so it makes a nice complement to other books.

Comment: Thanks. Am I right in saying that modelling the term structure is the most important part of IR modelling? I read the IR chapter of kwon yesterday is it all seemed to revolve around different parameters of the orstein-uhlenbeck process. I will try to source your first book as well.